# What is Full URL pattern for WordPress' Sites when Multisite is setup?

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, wordpress

What is WordPress' Full URL for Multisite? Is there even such a concept? I am referring to full notation equivalents of this pattern:

- .http://www.website.com/blog_1/lang/post_222/
- .http://www.website.com/blog_2/lang/post_333/
- .http://www.website.com/blog_3/lang/post_444/

Are these processed or converted to something like these? I would assume that they are so I asked the question.

- .http://www.website.com/index.php?param=/blog_1/lang/post_222/
- .http://www.website.com/index.php?param=/blog_2/lang/post_333/
- .http://www.website.com/index.php?param=/blog_3/lang/post_444/

---

**Some Background:**

I'm going to need it to perform URL rewriting using NGINX that includes the subsites' names (blog_1, blog_2, blog_3). Like this:

**Browser URL**: .http://www.website.com/de/news/post_444/ **-> Backend URL**: .http://www.website.com/blog_news/de/post_444/

I am able to rewrite the URL when it reaches NGINX but to get the result of the "new" URL, I can either do the following:

1. **proxy_pass**. But this is going to trigger a separate request, buffer it in the NGINX machine and serve it back as the response to the original request.
2. Pass the blog name and parameters to a WordPress index file e.g. /index.php?param=/blog_name/etc/.

---

I would appreciate any help or any advice you can share.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that what I was asking is not something that is revealed by creators as it could pose a security risk. It could also be something that is not ideal to use because the new versions of WP may change approach etc.

Regarding my case, I simplified the URL pattern. I removed the /lang/ part of the URLs and renamed the WordPress blogs so as to minimize the rewriting. This solution required me to 301-redirect the old patterns so as not to affect SEO-ranking.

I'm only maintaining English content now so it's a good enough solution for now. But eventually, I will need a more flexibility when I need to serve translated content.